# JSON on Swift: Array to String/TextField Text

Tags: arrays, json, swift, swift2

I have problem with JSON Array that I want to be display on textfield. JSON is taken from URL. This is JSON structure:

```
    {
    description = „This is short decripton”;
    );
    more-description =     (
        „this is first line”,
        „this is second line”,
        „third line”,
        „etc”,
        „etc”
    );
    one-more-description =     (
        „this is first line”,
        „this is second line”,
        „third line”,
        „etc”,
        „etc”
    );
```

And this is my code:

```
    import UIKit

    class RecipeViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionTextField: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var more-descriptionTextField: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var one-more-descriptionTextField: UITextView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    let urlAsString = "http://JSON-Address.com"
    let url = NSURL(string: urlAsString)!
    let urlSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()


    let jsonQuery = urlSession.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { data,   response, error -> Void in
    do {
        if let jsonDate = data, let jsonResult = try      NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonDate, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
            print(jsonResult)

            let jsonDescription = jsonResult["description"] as? String
            print("result: \(jsonDescription)")

            let jsonMoreDescrp: AnyObject? = jsonResult["more-description"] as? Array<AnyObject>
            print("result: \(jsonMoreDescrp)")

            let jsonOneMoreDescrp: AnyObject? = jsonResult["one-more-description"] as? Array<AnyObject>
            print("result: \(jsonOneMoreDescrp)")

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

              self.descriptionTextField.text = jsonDescription
               self.more-descriptionTextField.text = jsonMoreDescrp as? String
                self.one-more-descriptionTextField.text = jsonOneMoreDescrp as? String

            });


        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }


    })
    jsonQuery.resume()
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
```

The problem is with jsonMoreDescrp & jsonOneMoreDescrp. Althought I've changed it to String, after running Xcode the result is empty. jsonDescription of course works, but this is just simple string.

```
I know I'm doing something wrong with Array, but - can you tell me what?
```

Answer (score 0):

jsonMoreDescrp & jsonOneMoreDescrp are array. so, you can call like this

```
  self.more-descriptionTextField.text = jsonMoreDescrp[indexValue] as? String
  self.one-more-descriptionTextField.text = jsonOneMoreDescrp[indexValue] as? String
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Nope, after changing to "self.more-descriptionTextField.text = jsonMoreDescrp [jsonResult] as? String" the result is empty textfiled :(

Answer (score 0):

[**Updated**] As Sudhir noticed there is also error in code, try this to show comma separated strings:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

              self.descriptionTextField.text = jsonDescription
               self.more-descriptionTextField.text = (jsonMoreDescrp as? [String])?.joinWithSeparator(",") ?? ""
                self.one-more-descriptionTextField.text = (jsonOneMoreDescrp as? [String])?.joinWithSeparator(",") ?? ""
            });
```

Validate JSON structure online before using http://jsonlint.com/

Valid JSON:

```
{
    "description": "This is short decription",
    "more-description": [
        "this is first line",
        "this is second line",
        "third line",
        "etc",
        "etc"
    ],
    "one-more-description": [
        "this is first line",
        "this is second line",
        "third line",
        "etc",
        "etc"
    ]
}
```

Comment: I think the code is also has a error. Did you look that you have type casted array to string directly where you assign into textfield ?

Comment: Nope, but I've checked JSON through JSON Validator sites. It's OK. The only problem that I have is with implement JSON array ("more-description") into TextField. Console shows everything is OK, but Simulator is empty. Only first object ("descritpion") works, but this is just simple String.

Comment: You are right. There are errors in code when casting array of string to string. I have updated answer

Comment: Array has an index. Am I right? According to your code which index of string you want to show in textfield ? Can you elaborate me? Accessing the array first you have to put your index then convert to string.

Comment: description is this string "["this is first line", "this is second line", "third line", "etc", "etc"]"

Comment: Sorry, method joinWithSeparator doesn't work. Error: Consecutive statemenst on a line must be separated by ';' (after String?)
Then: Cannot assign value of type String?? to type String 
And: Type of expression is amibiguous without more context
After few modifications: joinWithSeparator is not a member type od String

Comment: self.more-descriptionTextField.text = (jsonMoreDescrp as? [String])?.joinWithSeparator(",") ?? ""

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, if it not works comment me the error you come across.

```
self.more-descriptionTextField.text = jsonMoreDescrp[indexValue].stringValue
self.one-more-descriptionTextField.text = jsonOneMoreDescrp[indexValue].stringValue
```

`indexValue` is the key of the value you want in the json.

Comment: Above Code not using Swiftyjson or Other Library

Answer (score 0):

try this code, it is much easy to use.
First of all parse all elements of map to the variables and than do what you want with knowing structure of just created variables.

```
let task = session.dataTask(with: url!) {
        (data, response, error) in
        do {
           let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String : AnyObject]
            if let desc = json["description"] as? String,
               let moreDesc = json["more-description"] as? [String],
               let oneMoreDesc = json["one-more-description"] as? [String] {
               dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

           self.descriptionTextField.text = moreDesc
           self.more-descriptionTextField.text = moreDesc.joinWithSeparator("/n")
           self.one-more-descriptionTextField.text = oneMoreDesc.joinWithSeparator("/n")

        });

               }

        } catch let error {
            print (error)
        }
    }

    task.resume()
```

I have not tested it, but it should work. Feel free to ask.